# Opening ports for Windows Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: sql-server, azure, port, virtual-machine, sql-server-2012

I have a Sql Server instance installed on my Azure Virtual Machine.  I've changed the port for Sql Server to...let's say 4849.  I opened this port in Windows Firewall and established the endpoint for both TCP and UDP.  I check to see if the port is open via http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ and it's still closed.  What am I missing here?

I'm utilizing SQL Server 2012 SP1 on Windows Server 2012.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I ended up just installing the Sql Server Image that Azure offers.  That seemed to connect immediately without issue once I added the endpoint.  Thanks for everyone's answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how this service checks for opened ports, but if it doing so by sending "ping" command then it may not work. You would need to do additional stuff for that to work. Please check this blog post for more details: http://blogs.biztalk360.com/windows-azure-virtual-machines-virtual-network-may-not-ping-automatically/.

Answer (score 1):

Does this need to be accessible to the outside world?  If so, you will need to open it on your firewall and have the firewall forward traffic on that port to your VM.

Also, you might need to check the config of your VM network adapter, if it's using NAT to share the hosts IP address, you might encounter problems, depending on what host you're using, I find that bridged mode works best so that the VM can use it's own IP address on the network.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also try this one to enable PING command for Azure virtual machine: http://blogs.biztalk360.com/windows-azure-virtual-machines-virtual-network-may-not-ping-automatically/